# Why can't I commit a psd (Photoshop) file to SVN?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I tried to commit psd file to svn but it didn't let me do it.

Error message:

> Commit failed (details follow): PUT of
>   '/svn/.../!svn/wrk/243a5d81-c1c1-f545-8346-5e8399121cb4/Design.psd':
>   Could not send request body: An
>   established connection was aborted by
>   the  software in your host machine.
>   (http://...)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Was any program using the file when you tried to commit?

Comment: Were you pinching your network cable at the time?

Comment: I have the same problem but with a DLL-file.

Comment: I have the same problem. The http://.... address that is redacted in the original question is the address of the server - so I think it's being aborted by the server, not something at the client end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you use up to date VisualSVN Server and svn client versions and that there are no problems with your antivirus, firewall, proxy, network. Note that sometimes an antivirus can cause such problems and only full uninstall of the antivirus software helps. Therefore, you may need to contact support of your antivirus, firewall or proxy for help.

- On the client side, add the location of user working copies to antivirus exclusions and add your SVN client to the exclusions, too.
- If you run an antivirus application on the server computer, you should make sure that the antivirus does not touch VisualSVN Server services and repositories. Antivirus applications, active firewalls, and traffic scanners tend to intercept plain HTTP traffic and HTTPS traffic in some cases too and may cause the problems that look as connectivity or performance -related at first glance.

  Please make sure that the antivirus does not touch traffic to and from VisualSVN Server, add the location where you store your repositories and VisualSVN Server services to the exclusion (exception) list of the antivirus. You should add the repositories root directory (C:\Repositories\, by default) and these services to the exclusion (exception) list of the antivirus so that its real-time protection does not interfere:

  - %VISUALSVN_SERVER%bin\VisualSVNServer.exe
  - %VISUALSVN_SERVER%bin\vdfssvc.exe
  - %VISUALSVN_SERVER%bin\vsvnjobsvc.exe
  - %VISUALSVN_SERVER%bin\vrepocfgsvc.exe

BTW, modern VisualSVN Server versions have a rich web interface and it supports viewing PSD (Adobe Photoshop) and AI (Adobe Illustrator) files as well as DOCX (Microsoft Word) and PDFs. [**Try the feature on the demo server**](https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#documents).

Answer (score -1):

It is all about the connection speed and the size of the file you want to commit. If you have slow connection please try committing when nobody other than svn process uses internet. It may help svn to use all the bandwidth of the internet connection.

After all if you have same problem you should update your custom-httpd.conf file in your VisualSVN server like the following code:

```
Timeout 300000
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
KeepAliveTimeout 500000
```

Comment: Can't add a comment due to my rep but just wanted to add onto mehdi's answer. For those searching for the file to edit. The file name is actually httpd-custom.conf
Also as expected the file is in %Program Files%/VisualSVN Server/conf/